# Loading some models in a generic view, breaking concepts?

Tags: django, django-generic-views

First of all I'm a beginner in `Django` world so maybe what I'm trying to do is crazy or it's a misunderstanding of concepts, so here we go:

How we can see, generic view save us a lot of time for that common patterns we use all the time in our templates, one of these is the `ListView` that retrieve a list of our model according to a set of attributes

```
 from models import Post
 from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView 


    class PostListView(ListView):
        model = Post
        template_name = 'blog/post_list.html'
```

We bind our `Post` model for make a `ListView` an set `post_list.html` as our template but... what happen when in our template we need to show more than one model? Imagining with this show a list of posts but we want to show another list of something in this template, for this purpose we can do that with generic views? or we have to do as old usual?

Comment: So, you want to show two lists of two different objects in one view?

Comment: For example... it's possible?

Comment: Yes, but not with generic views (which generally only work on a single object).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know :)

Comment: If I understand you right - yes, it is possible. But you can't do this with Django's built-in generic views - you should write your own. I have some similar views. Please, provide a concrete example, where you want to use them. Perhaps, a easier way is exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add additional information such as another list of unrelated models to the context passed to the template. The Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context) shows the example below:

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from books.models import Publisher, Book

class PublisherDetail(DetailView):

    model = Publisher

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(PublisherDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
        context['book_list'] = Book.objects.all()
        return context
```